# What does mean granular knowledge and gene sequencig in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The granular knowledge provided by gene sequencing has transformed the
>   understanding of prehistory.

In this above line I speculate that **granular knowledge** means detail knowledge and **gene sequencing** means placing gene in correct order. If I am right then the meaning of the whole sentence is

> The detail knowledge provided by gene order has changed the
>   understanding of prehistory.

. I am not sure If I am right or wrong. It would be nice if anyone correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more granular something is, the more fine-grained it is, hence, in a figurative sense, the simpler it is, "simple" in the sense of "uncompounded".

For example, transactions with a DateTime column are temporally more granular than transactions with a simple Date column.  From the DateTime transactions we could isolate transactions occurring within a particular *hour* of the day, say, or even a particular minute or second of the day, whereas with a Date column the greatest possible temporal *refinement* is the day.

Answer (score 0):

While you may be right about **granular knowledge**, your interpretation of **gene sequencing** is incorrect. [Gene sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_sequencing) is a laboratory process.